# Sport app, when best to ask to review app

Tags: ios, mobile-application

I'm a (proud) owner of a 5 year old running app for iOS & Android. The app is to train both beginners and experienced runners with training schedules (30 lessons in 10 weeks). When do you think it's the best time to ask a user for a review?

1. After landing on the dashboard X times
2. After completing a run X times and viewing their stats (not my favo)
3. After completing a training schedule (+/- 10 weeks of running)
4. After viewing total stats / last runs
5. When viewing the achievements

My opinion: After completing 2 weeks of training, after closing my current training and landing on the Dashboard.

**And:** What 'popup' message would you recommend?

"How is training going with X?"
"I am satisfied" / "Can do better".

**[EDIT]** Why this isn't a duplicate of [this topic](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40717/asking-feedback-rating-for-a-mobile-app): The usage of an sport app differs from other apps like games or news related apps. As you actively use the app during your excise you want as little information before, during, and after training. This means a different way of interacting and asking for a review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a runner I am most likely to recommend an app right after I am on some kind of streak. The streak could be as small as a week or a full training period. You could say "Great job! You have run x days in a row. If you are enjoying this app...."

Here is another way to you could try: You can insert a banner in between the feed/dashboard/stats page.

[image]