# Best practices for asking user to "Rate this app"?

Tags: usability

Is it more common to place the "Rate this app" prompt to be triggered when the user has made it to a certain point in the app (after beating a certain level, gaining access to a certain tab, etc). Or is is more common to have the prompt on a timer and just go off after the user has been using the app for a certain period of time and is in a place where a message won't interrupt their session.

Are their pro's and con's of each or is only one practice really executed?

Comment: A more general but related question was asked some time ago: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40717/asking-feedback-rating-for-a-mobile-app. Probably the comments and answers provide further information to you.

Answer (score 3):

You should not interrupt the user's flow. Frequently asking to rate the app is bad.

If the user beats some level there will be a positive vibe in him. Utilize this vibe and ask him to rate the app. **"Congratulations Dude(or user_name),That was awesome!! Would you mind taking a moment to rate us?"**

A swipe banner is always better than a popup.

Comment: Then again, I've never followed a popup or banner to rate an app.  If I want to rate it, it's either because I think it's especially good or has some important flaw.  I don't rate an app just because it tells me to.